# Create Shortcut to VMware

Tags: linux, centos, gnome3, vmware, desktop

How would I create a shortcut to VMWare player on CentOS 7 desktop?

A lot of people say it's not possible to create shortcuts on Gnome 3, I have seen it working with a special file, but i'm not sure how to get it working with VMWare.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the *.desktop file?
This is my desktop file to vmware player.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=VMware Player
Comment=Run a virtual machine
Exec=/PATH/TO/bin/vmplayer %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=vmware-player
StartupNotify=true
Categories=System;
MimeType=application/x-vmware-vm;application/x-vmware-enc-vm;x-scheme-handler/vmrc;
```

*You have to put your own path to vmplayer in the `Exec` field*

Its path is

`/usr/share/applications/vmware-player.desktop`

Comment: Thanks, this helped. The location was slightly different for me, but the advice was useful.

Comment: Your welcome, i write the path for debían 8 *.desktop files. It would be nice if you accept my answer or tell me what i have to do to improve it.